# JavaScript, J Query help needed, how do i sum span values as shown in the HTML below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i sum up values in a html span. I am stuck, as the codes i have tried do not get the html values.

```
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="x_Defd1_price" id="x_Defd1_price_0" value="3">
        12

</label>

<label class="radio">

<input type="radio" name="x_Defd2_price" id="x_Defd2_price_0" value="4">
         13

</label>

<label class="radio">

<input type="radio" name="x_Defd3_price" id="x_Defd3_price_0" value="5">
        14
</label>
```

Comment: Not enough information to help. Do you have some markup that could help explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Show some Html as well as what you have tried

Comment: Please edit, select your code and mark it as code with the { }-button, it will make it much easier to read!

Comment: What are you trying to sum?  Your question says "span", but there are no spans in your HTML.  Are you trying to sum the values in the `<input>` tags?  Or the text in the `<label>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, it seems like you're trying to get the total of 12 + 13 + 14? Is that correct? For that, using jQuery, you would just do:

```
var total = 0;
$('label.radio').each(function(){
  total += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
alert('total: ' + total);
```

Or if you're trying to get the sum of the `<input>` values, you would use:

```
var total = 0;
$('label.radio input').each(function(){
  total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
alert('total: ' + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do using javascript if I am understanding your question correctly.

```
Var val1 = document.getElementById('x_Defd1_price_0').value;
Var val2 = document.getElementById('x_Defd1_price_1').value;
Var val3 = document.getElementById('x_Defd1_price_2').value;
Var sum = val1 + val2 + val3;
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use a tag like  then simple get these elements using javacript or jQuery and perform any action what you want.

```
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="x_Defd1_price" id="x_Defd1_price_0" value="3">
        <p class="a_new_spam">12</p>

</label>
```

Set properties of "a_new_spam" class in your style.